# CSS fade effect background color

Tags: html, css

hello guys i running a fade effect with css, works perfect, i want change the color when get the fade but i had no success.

the fade change color if i use without image, but if i using with i image does not work.

example:
i tried :

```
background-color: red;
```

but i had no success, anyway somebody know how can make the fade backgroundbe a different color? right now just going to white, its possible do another color?

right now i have a image and whe i hover the mouse appear a fade white effect, i just wanna change the white to red.

php:

```
<img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/public/images/get_.jpg" class="slide fade " alt="" />
```

css:

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;


   }

   .fade:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a Fiddle](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/BNqwmQ) that overlays a background: red; over a div containing your image of choice.

HTML

```
<div class="box fade"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
}

.fade {
  position: relative;

}

.fade:after {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover:after  {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: hello tania, thanks for the help,i checked your code in codepen,  but when i hover my mouse in your image does not do anything. :(

Comment: u can see here my code, i am trying make the background red when i hover the mover but i have no sucess: http://jsfiddle.net/1vovcy1q/